# Cakephp 2 retrieve data where condition depends on child table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am having a strange behavior which I do not understand with my cakephp 2.
In my Model 'Study' I have a has many relation:

```
class Study extends AppModel {

public $hasOne = array(
    'SubjectFilter' => array(
        'className' => 'Subject_filter',
        'dependent' => true
    )

    );


public $hasMany = array(

    'ExecutedStudyTable' => array(
            'className' => 'ExecutedStudyTable',
            'foreignKey' =>'study_id',
            'dependent' => true,
    ),   

);
```

The ExecutedtStudyTable Model looks like this:

```
class ExecutedStudyTable extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo= array(
    'Study' => array(
        'className' => 'Study',
        'foreignKey' => 'study_id'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('ExecutedStudyTable.user_id = User.id')
    )

);
```

}
When retrieving data everything looks good until I try to do this:

```
        $studies = $this -> Study -> find('all',array(
 'conditions' => array(
            'Study.user_id' => $cId,
            'OR'=>array(
                array('Study.state'=>'active'),
                array('Study.state'=>'rehearsal')
            ),                
            'SubjectFilter.studyCode'=>null,
            'ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>$user
 )
    ));
```

I get this error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ExecutedStudyTable.user_id' in 'where clause'`

Cakephp builds this query like this:

```
 SELECT `Study`.`id`, `Study`.`user_id`, `Study`.`created`, `Study`.`modified`, `Study`.`started`, `Study`.`completed`, `Study`.`title`, `Study`.`description`, `Study`.`numberParticipants`, `Study`.`state`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`firstName`, `User`.`familyName`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`addressStreet`, `User`.`addressCity`, `User`.`addressZip`, `User`.`phone1`, `User`.`phone2`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`passwordResetCode`, `User`.`passwordResetDate`, `User`.`sendUsernameDate`, `SubjectFilter`.`id`, `SubjectFilter`.`study_id`, `SubjectFilter`.`m`, `SubjectFilter`.`f`, `SubjectFilter`.`age18_24`, `SubjectFilter`.`age25_34`, `SubjectFilter`.`age35_44`, `SubjectFilter`.`age45_54`, `SubjectFilter`.`age55plus`, `SubjectFilter`.`studyCode` FROM `eyevido`.`studies` AS `Study` LEFT JOIN `eyevido`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Study`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `eyevido`.`subject_filters` AS `SubjectFilter` ON (`SubjectFilter`.`study_id` = `Study`.`id`) WHERE `Study`.`user_id` = 1402402538 AND ((`Study`.`state` = 'active') OR (`Study`.`state` = 'rehearsal')) AND `SubjectFilter`.`studyCode` IS NULL AND `ExecutedStudyTable`.`user_id` = 1130451831
```

The ExecutedStudyTable is not joined like the SubjectFilter and no alias is defined for the table. Why is this working correctly on the hasOne relation and not on the hasMany? Where do I make the mistake?

I appreciate your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter a model by associated model's field, one way is by [Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Note: Mention proper table name for model ExecutedStudyTable. Also mention the join condition between two tables.

```
$studies = $this->Study->find('all',array(
 'fields' => array('Study.*'),
 'joins' => array(
      array('table' => 'executed_study_table', // Table name
        'alias' => 'ExecutedStudyTable',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'ExecutedStudyTable.<field name> = Study.<field>', // Mention join condition here
        )
    )
 ),
 'conditions' => array(
        'Study.user_id' => $cId,
        'OR'=>array(
            array('Study.state'=>'active'),
            array('Study.state'=>'rehearsal')
        ),                
        'SubjectFilter.studyCode'    => null,
        'ExecutedStudyTable.user_id' => $user
  ),
  'recursive' => -1
));
```

Comment: Okay I can do this, like you said, but why is the join working automatically for the hasOne relation with my model SubjectFilter? I do not get an error message for this and the join is done by cake as you see in the SQL query

Comment: Actually, it has nothing to do with the hasOne relation. Join works independently. That's why we have added `recursive = -1`

Comment: In older versions of CakePHP 1 and 2, it's difficult to filter data based on associated model. We can use Containable behavior but I prefer JOIN. Containable behavior is more suitable and flexible for CakePHP 3.x

Comment: But this will fail when there aren't any records in the ExecutedStudyTable for joining. Is there a way to say something like 'ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>$user or ExecutedStudyTable is Empty?

Comment: It will work when performing a left join and not an inner join:
'joins' => array(
      array('table' => 'executed_study_table', // Table name
        'alias' => 'ExecutedStudyTable',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'ExecutedStudyTable.<field name> = Study.<field>', // Mention join condition here
        )
    )
 ),